# query is running but failed to create view in biqquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I would like to create view by using multiple tables . While creating view getting "FAiled to save View , column not found do u mean that this column" but if you run the query . I am getting data. Can you please help to resolve this issue

Comment: If you are using legacy SQL, please try using standard SQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing project(s) to be specified in your query
You should fully qualify tables as
[project:dataset.table] if you are using Legacy SQL or
`project.dataset.table` if you are using Standard SQL